# How to force a val in a class to be immutable in class using class type in OCaml

Tags: class, types, ocaml

Let's say I have this :

```
class type point_t =   
    object  
        val x : int  
        method getx : int  
        method move : int -> unit  
     end;;
```

I can write a class like this and it will work :

```
class point : point_t =   
    object  
        val mutable x = 0  
        method getx = x  
        method move d = x <- x + d   
    end;;
```

Now suppose that I want to create a class type that would NOT allow a class to be defined with a mutable val x (I want x to be immutable). Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, so if you don't want to allow implementations to use a mutable variable it is better just to hide it all and expose functional getter/setter:

```
class type point_t = object(self)  
  method get_x : int  
  method with_x : int -> self
  method move : int -> self  
end;;
```

You may omit `with_x` method if you want to allow updates only via the `move` method.

The reasoning for this is that a class with a mutable version of a variable is a proper subclass of a class with immutable version of the same variable, as it has the same set of operations, plus one more - an ability to set the variable. So, any abstraction over a type `point_t` can be applied to a class instance with and without a mutability (although it will not be able to mutate the variable). Note, that the opposite is not possible, if you will define the class type `point_t` with a mutable `x`, and will try to implement it with an immutable one, then the type system will complain. As your implementation doesn't provide all the operations.

Also, there is one thing that you possibly miss. Although, the class `point` has a mutable variable `x` this mutability is actually sealed (i.e., hidden) by the type constraint `point_t`. So, no matter what is the implementation, the interface is strictly defined to have immutable `x`:

```
class the_point = object 
    inherit point
    method! move d = x <- x - d
end

method! move d = x <- x - d
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
Error: The instance variable x is not mutable
```

Your confusion may arise from the fact that you have some experience with Java/C++ style of OOP, where class types are nominal, and a class can became a subclass of another class only by explicit inheritance. In OCaml a class is a subclass of another class if it is a *syntactical* superset of it, i.e., if it has at least all fields of the super class. There is no need to inherit from a super class, to become its subclass. And `class point : point_t` is not an inheritance, but a type constraint, that says: here is the class expression, that implements `point_t` class (and maybe more), please, make sure that it is true and expose only `point_t` interface to the outsiders.

And a final note, I've specifically denoted term *sub classing* as the *syntactic* super set of a super class to emphasize the fact that inheritance and sub classing do not imply subtyping. The latter is the semantics (i.e., the behavior of an instance), the former is syntax, i.e., a set of code fragments. Subclassing gives you a code reuse, the ability to copy the code from superclasses (as `inherit` is actually just copy/pasting the code of super class to your sub class). The subtyping gives you the polymorphism - an ability to use the same abstraction on different implementations.

Comment: I find it weird that there's no difference in permissions between val x and val mutable x in point_t but I guess there's maybe not really a need for it. Just started learning OCaml a few weeks ago. Thanks !

Comment: @J-Lab, there is a difference, I've updated my answer with the reasoning behind this behavior. Hope, it will help you.